# Show that (X) is a prime Ideals

Tags: ring-theory

If $R$ is an integral domain then the principal ideal generated by $x$ in the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is a prime ideal. This proof was an if and only poof. I solved the first direction but i am having problem with this direction. Any clues.

Answer (score 4):

**Lemma**: $P$ is a prime ideal if and only if $R/P$ is an integral domain.

Now notice that $$R[x]/(x) \cong R.$$

Comment: yeah i notice that but how does this help me show that (X) is a prime ideals

Comment: oh i see i just find that lemma now i am going to see if can understand it so i can apply it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the theorem in Robert's answer then, directly

$\qquad\qquad \begin{align} &\ \  x\mid fg = f(0)g(0)\, +\, x(\cdots)\\
 \iff&\ \  x\mid  f(0)\,g(0)\\
 \iff&\ \  f(0)g(0) = 0\\
 \iff&\ \  f(0)\!=\!0\ \ {\rm or}\ \ g(0)\!=\!0\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ R\ \ {\rm domain}\\
 \iff&\ \  \quad x\mid f\ \ \ {\rm or}\quad x\mid g\end{align}$

Thus $\ x\mid fg\iff x\mid f\ \ \ {\rm or}\ \ \ x\mid g,\ $ so $\,x\,$ is prime (by definition)